# create page with custom layout SharePoint online

Tags: rest, sharepoint, dynamic, sharepoint-online

I am new to SharePoint 365 development and I have a project to create a
SharePoint with different pages, which must be dynamically created. My question is   whether it is possible to dynamically create a page with a custom page layout   using the REST API? If not, are there other options?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did find out how to work around the issue.. It is possible to create an .aspx page in a document library and then insert a template so that it works and looks the way you want.